# How to use vs code to manage scattered files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Most of my projects have files scattered in different directories. I am just checking out vs code and am wondering if there are sufficient project management features to suit this need.

Ideally, it would have a way to place files from different locations into a named 'group'. The group could be opened and closed (I mean brought in to view, or loaded into vs code) easily via a pick list. A file could be moved from group A to group B; the file location on disk would remain the same, just it's membership in a group would change. I would want the relationsip between the groups and the related files to be savable so that the same groups and associated files would be accessible after vs code as been closed and the opened again.

vs code looks very capable, but I've only gone over a few tutorials and haven't use it for anything real yet. It does say it's file and folder centric, and OS level folders are not how these files are organized. Maybe there is a feature I've not seen yet or a plugin.

Comment: no input at all?

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for something similar, but unable to find a solution.  I did find a work-around though.  There is an extension called [File Group](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.FileGroup) that allows creating a group of file with full path to locations of each file.  New to vsCode myself, it took me a while to figure it out, but worth the effort.  Hint, once installed, go to settings, Extensions, File Group and Edit in settings.json to add your file list.